# How to serve React from subpath using Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, devops

My setup is a Django application served with gunicorn and Nginx. I am adding React one page at a time so therefore I need to only serve specific pages from React. To make it easier to route using Nginx I decided to make every React route start with `/v2/`.

Therefore the Nginx conf file looks like this right now:

```
upstream backend_server {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    deny 143.198.76.27;

    location /v2/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        ....
    }
}
```

In the `package.json` I added the homepage:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "homepage": "/v2",
   ...
}
```

I have also tried adjusting my `BrowserRouter`'s `basename`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/v2">
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And for testing purposes I have made 3 routes:

```
function App() {
  return (
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<CounterPage/>}/>
     <Route path="/v2" element={<CounterPage/>}/>
     <Route path="/v2/test" element={<CounterPage/>}/>
   </Routes>
  );
}
```

My nginx build process for the Docker image looks like this (and the files are verified to be there):

```
FROM ghcr.io/digibrainllc/example/frontend:latest as build

# Create production build
RUN npm run build

# Production Nginx image with frontend build files
# to be served by Nginx
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

# Copy the frontend build files over to the directory
# which Nginx serves from
COPY --from=build /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Remove the default Nginx settings
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /nginx/conf/nginx.prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

`example.com/v2`:

> 404 Not Found

I need all `example.com/v2` routes serving React and the rest routed to Django.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. To examine more closely I looked at the Nginx logs: `docker logs [nginx_id]`.

During debugging I removed the `alias` and added a `root` to the main server block.

Then the nginx logs said the path was `/usr/share/nginx/html/v2/` where the file was not found. So I logged into the nginx container `docker exec -it [nginx_id] sh` and copied the build files from `/usr/share/nginx/html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/v2`. This allowed the files to be discovered...

So the changes were to:

- Add a root block in nginx
- Change my Dockerfile to copy the `frontend/build` files to `usr/share/nginx/html/v2` instead.

**Nginx.conf:**

```
upstream backend_server {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    deny 143.198.76.27;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /v2/ {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        ....
    }
}
```

**Nginx Dockerfile**:

```
# Copy the frontend build files over to the directory
# which Nginx serves from
COPY --from=build /frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html/v2
```

I knew it would be something simple XD